# Adding card to Apple Wallet

Tags: ios

```
 func addPaymentPassViewController(_ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController, generateRequestWithCertificateChain certificates: [Data], nonce: Data, nonceSignature: Data, completionHandler handler: @escaping (PKAddPaymentPassRequest) -> Void) {
```

I am getting certificates [Data], from this method. How to sign this certificates with CA Authority and convert them to base64 string.

How to download root CA to validate this chain

Can anyone help me on this.

Thank you

Comment: Are you able to find the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to extract this data from `certificates: [Data]`
this is my solution:

```
  let certificateLeaf = certificates[0].base64EncodedString();
  let certificateSubCA = certificates[1].base64EncodedString();
  let nonceString = nonce.base64EncodedString();
  let nonceSignature = nonceSignature.base64EncodedString();
```